# Can you break down this string manipulation function for me ? (JS)

Tags: javascript, string

I think I'm asking this kind of question in the right place, the "discussion" tag's description seems to fit. If I'm mistaking, well I'm sorry :s

So here goes, my question concerns a [codefights](https://codefights.com) challenge. The challenge was:

> Given a string, transform it (by shuffling its contents) into a palindrome!
>   A palindrome is a string that reads the same left-to-right and right-to-left.
>
> Example:
>       "abcd"->"imp"
>       "cdcd"->"cddc"
>       "AABBaabb33!!??"->"!3?ABabbaBA?3!"
>
> - The input is a string and can contain letters ,digits and/or ? ,!
> - If it is not possible you should return imp (for impossible) and if there is more than one solution return the first one in the lexicographic order

I failed solving it so I went and had a look at the best solution the day after:

```
function outputString(s) {
  s = s.split(a = b = c = "").sort()
  i = 0
  while (x = s[i])
    x == s[++i] ?
        [a += x, c = x + c, i++] :
        b += x
  return b[1] ? "imp" : a+b+c
}
```

But I don't understand it.
Let me try to explain what I don't understand exactly:

- What exactly is this input for the split function ?
- I understand that inside the while there is a shorthand if but what is done in it is incomprehensible for me :s

I understand that these kind of question don't really have their place here but I think I managed to make it so that a short, to the point answer is possible.
If someone could break these two elements down for me. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: No real explanation, just an "expanded" version: http://jsfiddle.net/crzt4mhu/

Comment: `s.split(a = b = c = "")` isn't doing anything. I think the OP is trying to declare variables, without declaring variables :)

Comment: I don't think it's the best solution notationally, even if it is algorithmically. He has undefined variables. He's trying to save lines or characters by using `?` instead of `if`, and weirdly doing three assignments inside a fake array, thereby unduly confusing diligent students such as yourself.

Comment: Yes, I agree [torazaburo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo) but codefigths chose the best solution by picking the shortest one passing the tests.

It was my bad to pick the shortest one to see how it was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The split is actually `split("")` which returns an array of single character strings. The assignment is returning what was assigned, so the code is also initializing a, b and c there, but it doesn't affect the split.
2. In the `while` the program is looping through the ordered characters and creates the result the following way: add the letter after a and in front of c if the next letter is the same and step two ahead (note the additional i++), otherwise add the letter to b. In the end if there was more than one single letter (only one can be in the middle) return "imp" otherwise a+b+c (which will be the first solution when this algorithm is used).

See [expanded version](http://jsfiddle.net/crzt4mhu/) of [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas).

Comment: Your answer and [Andrea](http://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas)'s jsfiddle helped a lot !
Thanks a lot.